# Why isn't the rectangle moving?

Tags: python, pygame

This is my code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

#define the player
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
 def __init__(self):
  super(Player, self).__init__()
  self.surf = pygame.Surface((50, 25))
  self.surf.fill((255,255,255))
  self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()

 def update(self, pressed_keys):
  """
  if pressed_keys[K_UP]:
   self.rect.move_ip(0, -5)
  if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
   self.rect.move_ip(0, 5)
  """
  if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
   self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
  if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
   self.rect.move_ip(5, 0)

  #keep player on the screen
  if self.rect.left < 0:
   self.rect.left = 0
  elif self.rect.right > 400:
   self.rect.right = 400

#initialization
pygame.init()

#create the screen object
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 600))

#instantiate the player
player = Player()

running = True

#main loop
while running:
 for event in pygame.event.get():
  if event.type == KEYDOWN:
   if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
    running = False
  elif event.type == QUIT:
   running = False

 #draw the player to the screen
 screen.blit(player.surf, (200, 550))

 pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

 player.update(pressed_keys)

 #update the display
 pygame.display.flip()
```

Everything shows up, but I can't move the rectangle with my arrow keys without any error showed, help.. Thanks in advance! I also add a print to check if the pressed_keys work and it print without moving the rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

good to see that you are using `pygame`:D

In Python, it is important to write "good" code, which means the code should follow all syntactic rules, be properly indented, and most importantly, be clear and readable.

Here are some guidelines for fixing your code (following [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines):

1. Always indent your code by 4 spaces or a tab
2. A comment character (`"#"`) should always be followed by a space, i.e.: `"# <= there's a space there"`
3. There should never be too many empty consecutive new lines
4. Leave a space after a comma in a list/tuple/set, i.e. `(10, 10, 10)`

---

And here are some `pygame` guide lines:

1. You should not use `pygame.key.get_pressed()` explicitly to check for keypress at every loop
2. Check for keypress in `for event in pygame.event.get()`
3. Set a frame rate using `clock.tick`, minimum frame rate should be 30, this will keep the program at constant speed
4. Always fill your screen with a color, even if it's black, `screen.fill((0, 0, 0))`
5. Refill your screen after every loop. `screen.fill((0, 0, 0))`

---

Here is what you have been waiting for, *how to fix your problem*; it's quite simple actually. `screen.blit(player.surf, (200, 550))` you're blitting it where your location is set `(200, 550)`. Instead, what you probably want is to change it to `screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)`, which will blit the `player` to its location ("`rect`").

---

Here's a complete modified version of your code following all my suggestions:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


# define the player
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((50, 25))
        self.surf.fill((255, 255, 255))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()

    def update(self, pressed_keys):
        if pressed_keys == K_LEFT:
            self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
        if pressed_keys == K_RIGHT:
            self.rect.move_ip(5, 0)
        # keep player on the screen
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        elif self.rect.right > 400:
            self.rect.right = 400

# initialization
pygame.init()

# create the screen object
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 600))
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

# instantiate the player
player = Player()

# instantiate the ticker
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# mainloop
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                player.update(event.key)
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                player.update(event.key)
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    # draw the player to the screen
    screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)
    # update the display
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Excuse me, how can I set the position of the player? Thank you again.

Comment: To initially set the sprites location, replace `self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()` to `self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(center=(100, 100))`. Replace the tuple with `(x, y)`, and the `center` argument can be replaced with `topleft`, `topright`,` `top`, `bottom`... You can find all of them here: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect. After that, you can use `self.rect.move(x, y)` to move the sprite to the `x` and `y` cord. Or any of the combination: `self.rect.right = 10` or `self.rect.top = 100`...

Comment: `You should not use pygame.key.get_pressed() explicitly to check for keypress at every loop, it will make your code slower, and possibly, lag` - That's nonsense. It will not make the code slower. `pygame.key.get_pressed() ` is the right way to retrieve the state of a key. With your code, you can no longer hold the keys down to get a continuous movement. `Set a frame rate so it doesn't consume too much RAM ` - That's also nonsense. You set a frame rate so your game runs at a constant speed. That has nothing to do with RAM....

Comment: ... `Always fill your screen with a color, even if it's black` -  That's generally a good advice, until your game gets more complex or you use a background image; then it's better to redraw only the necessary parts of the screen. `how to fix your problem` - IMHO it would be better to just put the sprite into a group, and call `draw` on the group.

Comment: Thank you all. Excuses me, I found that as the time went by, the falling rectangle(enemy) in the same time become more and more, can any one tell me why and how to fix it. Thank you again.

Comment: Mind posting your code that contains the "falling rectangle"?